# Changing text color of PlusOneButton on Android

Tags: android, google-plus, introspection, google-plus-one

I have a plus one button on my xml file :

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
    xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
    android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    plus:size="tall"
    plus:annotation="inline"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

This PlusOneButton is using a default text color which is a grey. I would like to change this text color to black. 
I tried to add to my styles.xml this line, but it doesn't work.

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
```

I tried with this code too but doesn't work.

```
ViewGroup plusOneDummyView = (ViewGroup)mPlusOneButton.getChildAt(0);
Button button = (Button)plusOneDummyView.getChildAt(0);
button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?